# Python, the status_code showed 404

Tags: python, http-status-code-404

I want to download some audio files from a website:

```
def downloadAudio(audioURL):
    response = requests.get(audioURL)
    if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.mp3')
        temp_file.write(response.content)
        return temp_file
    else:
        print 'Download error: ', response.status_code
        return False
```

And I use it in this way:

```
temp_file = downloadAudio('http://www.izaodao.com' + audioLink)
```

Say the path is

> http://www.izaodao.com/app/zdword/burouti95.mp3

in past two days, it worked and returned mp3 file, but today it didn't and returned status_code 404
But I can still open this website, which means it exists.

I don't know what happened? Is that because I requested too frequently therefore my IP was blocked but why I can still open it through Chrome?

And how can I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps add a client header with a fake browser (or whatever it is called)?